# Why the refs to itemId cannot trigger the initialize event in Sencha Touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

This is the controller code:

```
Ext.define('XXX.controller.XXX', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        views: ['CustomView','CarouselView'],
        refs: {
            custom: "carouselview #customid"
        },
        control: {
            custom: {
                initialize : function() {
                    alert("it's loading")
                }
            }
        }
    },
    launch: function(){
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('XXX.view.CustomView'));
        console.log(this.getCustom())      // ——> This works, it is not undefined
    }
});
```

and this is the carousel view code:

```
Ext.define('XXX.view.CarouselView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Carousel',
    xtype: 'carouselview',

    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    config:{
        direction: 'horizontal',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'customview',
                itemId: 'customid'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Now it's the `customview` :

```
Ext.define('XXX.view.CustomView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'customview',
    config: {
        tpl:  XXX
    }
});
```

in the controllers's launch function, it can log the right value, but the `initialize` event can't be triggered.
And if i change refs to `{ custom: "customview" }`, the `initialize` event can be triggered.

Comment: Your first selector isn't correct. Think of it like CSS: you're basically saying "match on component with itemId of "customid" that is a _descendant_ of a "carouselview". Since the carouselview itself has the itemId of "customid", your selector should be "carouselview#customid"

Comment: @existdissolve no, `#customid` view is a subitem of carouselview. This selector works fine because `this.getCustom()` is a valid value means the correct component has been referenced. but i don't know why it doesn't work with the initialize function

Comment: how did you define "carouselview"?

Comment: @ThiemNguyen I have update the code. It's just an panel

Comment: @ThiemNguyen I'm sorry about the mistake i made. The code was not corret, because I write the custom view in wrong place. Now it's right. The problem is: the `refs -> customid` can be referenced in `launch` of controller, but the `initialize` of `customid` view cannot be triggered

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Just figured out that you are trying to initialize on something that get's the itemId on initialize :) Sorry, took me some time.

Basically the fireEvent('initialize') has already been in the past when you are trying to listen to it in the controller.

Use the xtype to initialize or simply:

```
Ext.define('XXX.view.CustomView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'customview',
    config: {
        tpl:  XXX
    },

    initialize: function() { // good way to use initialize inside the view, as it belongs to the view and there is not user input handled
    }
});
```

OR

```
Ext.define('XXX.controller.XXX', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        views: ['CustomView','CarouselView'],
        refs: {
            custom: ".carouselview .customview" // --> HERE use this
        },
        control: {
            custom: {
                initialize : function() {
                    alert("it's loading") // Yeah, now you are getting here
                }
            }
        }
    },
    launch: function(){ // --> this will be the same as if you are placing it in app.js launch
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('XXX.view.CustomView')); // --> here the initialize happends and this.getCustom() does not yet exists
        console.log(this.getCustom())      // ——> here this.getCustom() exists
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry about the mistake i made. The code was not corret, because I write the custom view in wrong place. Now it's right. The problem is: the `refs -> customid` can be referenced in `launch` of controller, but the `initialize` of `customid` view cannot be triggered. And i have test your code, it still not work because the `customid` is a subitem of carouselview, so the selector should be `.carouselview #customid`, now the `this.getCustomId()` works fine but the `initialize` still cannot be triggered.

Comment: can you update your code example, so that I can see if you are using initialize at another code part?

Comment: i have updated the code now. There is an information, the event still `initialized`, and the refs to `"customview"` can trigger the event.

Comment: Bruahahahaha, see my update. I didn't see it earlier. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: And try to get rid of the launch method, if not really necessary. This will be launched on start of the app and has nothing todo with the view. So I would prefer to have all launch items inside the app launch. Though there might be good reasons for having a launch method inside a controller ....

Comment: What event can achieve the same effect? And i think it is not the fault of `launch`, because the refs to `"customview"` can trigger the 'launch' event

Comment: why not use the code snippet I added. I will clean up my post, so it's easier find the code snippet From there you can use the initialize or you simply use  custom: ".carouselview .customview"

Comment: I know it would work. But i want to find a specific component named customid. Also, i want to know why that code didn't work

Comment: Why it did not work: if you instantiate a view and want the itemId to be set, that is happening during initialize. So what happens is 1) create view 2) fire event initialize 3) set the itemId and after that you are trying to listen to initialize, which will not be fired again. If you need to find a specific custom component it's up to you to come up with a unique path. Let's say you wrap that item inside a container (#meSpecific) go to the controller an add a ref for (.carouselview #meSpecific #customview). Voilá you have this one spefic item to listen for.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you (and someone answered below) misunderstand the use of `itemId` config.

Here is the difference between `id` and `itemId`:

- `id` is the global identifier of a component. It can be used directly as a selector in `Ext.ComponentQuery` class which `refs` uses behind the scene. So if you want something like `"carouselview #customid"`, you have to use `id` instead of `itemId`.
- `itemId` is the global identifier **within a class** from which the component derives from. For example, assume that you have an `Ext.Button` with `itemId: "myCustomButton"`, then you can have access to it via this refs: `button#myCustomButton` (please note that there's no space between them). This way, `Ext.ComponentQuery` first looks for all components xtyped `button`, then find the instance with that `itemId`.

So, if you want to use some string as "first-class" selector, you will have to use `id`. If you want to use `itemId`, you may want to always include its xtype before the `itemId`. Therefore, 2 possible solutions are:

- First solution (still use itemId): `custom: "carouselview customview#customid"`
- Second solution: keep your refs, but change `#customid` from `itemId` to `id`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. The first solution still not work. and the second solution works fine

Comment: no, i have tried that. But the `console.log(this.getCustom())` works fine in the `launch` of controller in both `"carouselview customview#customid"` or `"customview#customid"` ways

Comment: that's really odd. What happen if you try another event like ``painted``?

Comment: Just the same. When i changed the event to `painted`, even the refs to '"customview"' can not triggered `painted`. There is an information, the event still `initialized`, and the refs to `"customview"` can trigger the event.

Comment: and please do not go with id if you are destorying and recreating views

Comment: @ProtoBassi ``id`` works perfectly fine with ``autoDestroy:true``. But generally for best practice refs, ``itemId`` is way more preferred